# Add repeating index to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
name      food
mike     pizza  
mike    cookie  
mike    banana  
mary     apple  
mary      pear  
jane  broccoli
```

I want to add a sequential integer column that is unique to **name**, like this:

```
id  name      food
 1  mike     pizza  
 1  mike    cookie  
 1  mike    banana  
 2  mary     apple  
 2  mary      pear  
 3  jane  broccoli
```

Is there an elegant pandas one- (or two-) liner to do that? I'm new to pandas and suspect there's a way to do it using some combination of groupby and lambda, but I'm not making any progress.

Comment: `df["name"].astype("category").cat.codes`

Comment: Unique to each name, or unique to each consecutive grouping of names (which the posted answers seem to accomplish). With a sorted DataFrame these may be the same, but in general are not.

Comment: `df.groupby('name', sort=False).ngroup()+1` is likely what you want. It's unique per name, and the counter is based on the occurrence in the DataFrame, not any lexicographical sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.factorize`:

```
df['Id'] = pd.factorize(df['name'])[0] + 1
```

Output:

```
   name      food  Id
0  mike     pizza   1
1  mike    cookie   1
2  mike    banana   1
3  mary     apple   2
4  mary      pear   2
5  jane  broccoli   3
```

Then set_index Id:

```
df.set_index('Id')
```

Output:

```
    name      food
Id                
1   mike     pizza
1   mike    cookie
1   mike    banana
2   mary     apple
2   mary      pear
3   jane  broccoli
```

Comment: All of the other answers are great, and frankly I didn't realize how little I knew - everyone's solutions result in proper dataframe indexes -- which I didn't know were a thing; I just wanted the column of values, which this and fuglede's solutions accomplish in one line. This one appears to be sort-insensitive, which is a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

You could let

```
df['id'] = (df.name != df.name.shift(1)).cumsum()
```

Comment: what if the `name` values arnt sorted?

Comment: The provided example would suggest that they are. @Superduper?

Comment: Yes, in my case, they are sorted, so this answer works, but for general usage the factorize seems better. And just a note for future visitors: both this solution and the accepted solution work, but in my case resulted in a SettingWithCopyWarning (python 3.7 kernel in jupteryLab 0.35.3)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df.set_index((~df.name.duplicated()).cumsum())
      name      food
name                
1     mike   pizza  
1     mike  cookie  
1     mike  banana  
2     mary   apple  
2     mary    pear  
3     jane  broccoli
```